# FB API not returning albums

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is how I create the login Button (with photo_upload permission):

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true" perms="publish_stream, offline_access, photo_upload, share_item"></fb:login-button>
```

Then, I call the following function to retrieve the albums:

```
function getAlbum()
{
    console.log("retrieving the albums");
    FB.api('/me/albums', function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });

    return true;
}
```

but the response object is as follows:

```
Object
 Data: Array[0]
    length: 0
```

I am having 2 public albums, but I cant able to retrieve them with above code. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `photo_upload, share_item` where did you get these from?!

Comment: here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/prompt-permission/

Comment: This is an old resource, always check for the latest!

Comment: yeah, legacy FBML... thx for pointing out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the solution. the problem is that I missed the 'user_photos' permission.
Now, everything works fine :)